# Python send file is not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I have below code to take user inputs from names.html and then replace the variablenames in template1.docx, I am able to replace the variables successfully and the file is getting saved correctly to output_folder. I can also see the sqlite3 db is getting updated correctly, but the send_file option is not working. I am using python 3.10.11. I don't see any errors, but I don't get the file on browser.

I am not sure if I am missing anything, can you please help.

```
def replace_variables_in_docx(document_path, variables):
    document = Document(document_path)

    modified_variables = {}

    for key, value in variables.items():
        if value:
            modified_variables['var' + key] = value
        else:
            modified_variables['var' + key] = ''

    for key, value in modified_variables.items():
        for element in document.element.xpath('//*[text()[contains(., "' + key + '")]]'):
            text = element.text.replace(key, value)
            element.text = text

    output_folder = 'GeneratedSEDs'
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    account_name = variables.get('accountName', 'UnknownAccount')

    output_path = os.path.join(
        output_folder, generate_file_name(account_name))
    document.save(output_path)

    return output_path




def generate_file_name(account_name):
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
    quarter = (current_month - 1) // 3 + 1  
    return f"{account_name}_ServiceEngagementDocument_V1_{current_year}_Q{quarter}.docx"


@app.route('/submit_new', methods=['POST'])
def submit_new():

    form_data = request.form.to_dict()

    account_logo = request.files.get('accountLogo')
    if account_logo:

        account_logo.save(f'uploads/{account_logo.filename}')

    variables = {key: value for key, value in form_data.items() if value}

    modified_doc_path = replace_variables_in_docx("Template1.docx", variables)

    for key, value in variables.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")

    db_folder = "Customer-DBs"

    if not os.path.exists(db_folder):
        os.makedirs(db_folder)

    db_path = os.path.join(db_folder, "CustomerDBs.db")

    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS form_data (
            accountName TEXT,
            key TEXT,
            value TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY (accountName, key)
        )
    """)

    account_name = variables.get('accountName', 'UnknownAccount')
    for key, value in variables.items():
        cursor.execute("""
            INSERT OR REPLACE INTO form_data (accountName, key, value)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)
        """, (account_name, key, value))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    output_folder = 'GeneratedSEDs'
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, generate_file_name(account_name))

    response_data = {
        'message': 'Form submitted successfully!',
        'details': f"Received data: {request.form}"
    }

    return send_file(output_path, as_attachment=True, download_name=generate_file_name(account_name))
```